# Change disk that Dask writes

Tags: python, dask

I'm having a problem with Dask where I have no more space left on device. However I have a disk with much more space than /. How can I change the disk that Dask writes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using dask's distributed scheduler then you can control the storage directory with the `--local-directory` keyword

```
dask-worker scheduler:8786 --local-directory /tmp/my-worker-directory
```